# Swift: is perfect memory possible?

Tags: swift, xcode, memory

I’ve created a pretty complex shopping app, and am satisfied with the results. Everything is de-initialized properly, the instruments say there Is no memory leak. However, I find when I intensively  test the app, memory goes up slightly consistently. Disk space is fine. But every 5 minutes on the app, I’d say there is a 0.02MB increase (very minor). This is a quick delivery app, so I highly doubt anyone will ever be on it long enough at a time to even cause an increase of a whole MB. Should I be worried none the less? Is it possible to completely remove this slight increase? Or is should I go back to reviewing every line of code. This app doesn’t ever go over 50MB if that’s important (as in it runs low enough even after a 30 minute test that it won’t pass 50MB; hypothetically if I ran it for hours it would)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I be worried none the less?

I'd want to find out which objects are being retained, and then decide if it's important enough to fix.

It might be that those objects are totally benign or maybe they're doing something that really does matter to your app.

If it's a static array of strings in a cache which is slowly growing over time, then fine.

If it's a load of defunct ViewModels which are still in memory, all listening for notifications and all making network requests or altering user data - then kill them off.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I be worried none the less? Is it possible to completely remove this slight increase?

Run your app in Instruments with the Allocations tool and watch the allocations that happen when the app is sitting idle. Knowing the size and frequency of the allocations should help you figure out what's happening and better understand your app's memory growth.

You can't know whether you need to address these allocations until you understand what they are, but going through all your code line by line hoping to find the culprit is at best a very slow way to get to the bottom of the question. Xcode includes tools that can help you here, and using them will improve your app and help you learn to be a better developer.